# ReactJS Custom Hook always raised an error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

New to React, I explore the Custom Hooks, building a simple form manager:

First, the hook (in components/hooks folder):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const useJalonForm = () => {
    const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({})

    // Handle form submission
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        if (event) {
            event.preventDefault() // Don't really submit the form, let's handle by us
        }
    }

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        event.persist();
        setInputs(inputs => ({...inputs, [event.target.name]: event.target.value}));
      }

    
    return {
        handleSubmit,
        handleInputChange,
        inputs
    }
}

export default useJalonForm
```

Then in a component, I would like to use this hook:

```
import React from 'react'

import useJalonForm from './hooks/useJalonForm'

const CreateJalon = () => {
    // Hook destructuration to get every components
    const { inputs, handleInputChange, handleSubmit } = useJalonForm()

    return (<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label>Titre : </label>
            <input type="text" name="title" required onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputs.title} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <select name="segment" size="1" onChange={handleInputChange} value={inputs.segment}>
                <option value="">Sélectionner...</option>
                <option value="state">State</option>
                <option value="props">Props</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <button type="submit">
                Créer
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>)
}

export default CreateJalon
```

Form component was "mounted" from App:

```
import CreateJalon from './components/Jalon/CreateJalon'
  // ...
  render() {
    const { jalons } = this.state
    
    const jalonIteration = () => {
      return jalons.map((jalon) => {
        return <JalonComponent key={jalon.id} jalon={jalon} changeState={this.receiveJalon.bind(this)} />
      })
    }

    const form = () => {
      if (!jalons.length) {
        return CreateJalon()
      }
      return null
    }

    
    return (
      <div>
        <ToolbarComponent jalons={jalons} />

        { form() }

        
        { jalonIteration() }
      </div>
    )
  }
  // ...
```

The App is a class (not a functional component!), but when I run:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

So:

- Is it a practice to mix Classes and Functional,
- Why this message

Answer (score 1):

[Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) says :

Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

in your case :

```
 if (!jalons.length) {
        return CreateJalon()
      }
```

and beacase of calling CreateJalon function, its hooks will be called.
so you must modify your code like below :

```
 if (!jalons.length) {
        return CreateJalon
      }
```

also when you are using `form` its better to replace

```
{form()}
```

with:

```
{form}
```

Comment: First Uncaught is done, thanks, but with your updates, now, got a warning "Functions are not valid as React child... So... What's wrong then ?

Comment: replae jalonIteration() wiht jalonIteration